# Classe Converter para Cidades Brasileiras

Tags: exceção

Senhores, tenho duas combos em um form, sendo que o primeiro é carregado com os estados brasileiros, via rotina
de banco de dados.É passado a sigla do estado escolhido para uma rotina no meu controle, que chama uma rotina na minha classe de persistência, com o 
parâmetro.
 A rotina funciona (eu vejo no passo-a-passo), porém na hora de carregar a combo, gera a seguinte exceção: "Erro de validação: o valor é necessário". Eu não sei como fazer a classe converter.
Abaixo segue trecho do código:

Comment: Em que linguagem? Faltou o código..

Comment: Fabio, estou utilizando a linguagem Java. com JSF, Primefaces 5.0, o banco é o Oracle 11g.